# binary search tree node always NULL

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I know this may seem simple, but I have been scratching my head for the last few hours trying to figure out why whatever I do, thisNode is always NULL. Because this is null, it means that nothing actually ends up getting added to the tree. Does any have any ideas? Arghhh

```
struct node *tra(struct node * start, Type input) 
{
    struct node * thisNode = start;

    if (thisNode == NULL)
        return thisNode;
    else 
    {
        Type current = thisNode -> el;

        if (strcmp(input, current) > 0)
            return tra(thisNode -> right, input);
        else if (strcmp(input, current) < 0)
            return tra(thisNode -> left, input);
        else
        return thisNode;
    }
}

Ta insert(Type input, Ta ta) 
{
    if ((find(input, ta)) == FALSE) 
    {
        struct node *newEl = tra(ta -> head, input);
        newEl = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newEl -> el = input;
        newEl -> left = NULL;
        newEl -> right = NULL;
    }

    return ta;
}

Boolean find(Type input, Ta ta) 
{
    if (tra(ta -> head, input) == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry I should've rephrased the question. I meant do you have any ideas how I can correct this? I've been using a debugger for the last few hours trying to figure this out. I know that it is NULL because it always enters the first if statement, but I simply cannot figure out why this is the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14926949/905902 Is there any reason to repost the same question ?

Comment: @wildplasser Umm... that's a link to this URL... Did you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922802/c-binary-search-tree-implementation-insert)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. But they do look alike, don't they?

Comment: @wildplasser I see that both of these issues are connected, and it seems that your way in the previous question was the right way to go about solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
        struct node *newEl = tra(ta -> head, input);
        newEl = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

you allocate the new node, but then the pointer newEl get lost. Your function tra should return a pointer to the pointer, to let the insert function modify the node to which you attach the newly created node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as follows:

When there's nothing in the BST, this triggers in `tra`:

```
if (thisNode == NULL)
    return thisNode;
```

So then `newEl == NULL` in `insert`.

Then you `malloc` to assign the pointer `newEl` a new value pointing to allocated memory. But the original pointer which you returned still has the value of `NULL` (because giving a copy of a pointer a new value doesn't change the original pointer).

Options for dealing with this:

- Return a pointer to a pointer (`struct node **`) (and I think you'd also need to pass a pointer to a pointer as parameter to the `insert` function).
- Change your check in `tra` to look at the next element (and appropriate changes). For a linked-list it would look like: `if (thisNode->next == NULL) return thisNode;` and in `insert` you'd work with `newEl->next`. While generally a good option for linked-lists, this is a bit more effort for BSTs, since you need to return whether the left or right nodes were `NULL`, or perform this check again in `insert`.

  - Note - you'd have to work with either `newEl->left` or `newEl->right` in `insert`.
- Return by reference - this is probably the easiest option. Change `tra` to return `struct node *&` and change `newEl` declaration to `struct node *&newEl = ...`, and that's probably about all.

Comment: Ok so I've decided to go with the second option. But if i changed the check to `if (thisNode -> head == NULL)`, surely I don't need to make any changes in insert to workwith `newEl -> head`, because I have already return `newEl -> head` in `tra`?

Comment: Also, why would I need to check if `thisNode` has a `head` element? Surely the `tree` would have a head element?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Is there any way I can show you what I have done in order for you to see whether I am on the right track?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pWq5Y3YF if you look at the traverse method, thats what I've understood from your explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24676/discussion-between-user1899174-and-dukeling)